# Programmatically Terminate an iOS App Extension

Tags: ios, exit, ios8, terminate, ios-app-extension

Is there a way to programmatically terminate an iOS app extension?

This would be similar to how you can terminate an actual application with the call

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] terminateWithSuccess];
```

or the call

```
exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

Comment: the exit(0) thing works (as seen in the posts this is kind of a duplicate of)

Comment: or you can do `[self.extensionContext cancelRequestWithError:[NSError errorWithDomain:NSCocoaErrorDomain code:NSUserCancelledError userInfo:nil]];` where `self` is some view controller

Comment: that doesn't actually kill the extension, it just dismisses the view controller